# Need to copy only a portion of array string to another array

Tags: perl

This is my source array:

```
my @raw_stack = (
    'a1~a2~a3~a4~a5',
    'b1~b2~b3~b4~b5',
    'c1~c2~c3~c4~c5',
    'd1~d2~d3~d4~d5',
    'e1~e2~e3~e4~e5',
);
```

I want get the 3rd value in '~' pattern then place that
to another array.

The other array should now look like this:

```
my @other_stack = (
    'a3',
    'b3',
    'c3',
    'd3',
    'e3',
);
```

I could go about looping through the stack array then split
and push to another array, but i'm looking for a lean way
to code this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my @other_stack = map {(split/~/)[2]} @raw_stack;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` to list transform instead of `push`. Use `index`/`substr` or `unpack` if the items are fixed-width. This generally is faster than split, which uses regex.

Comment: It is misguided to pursue efficiency before an obvious and clear solution has proven to be inadequate. Always go for readability and elegance before anything else.

Comment: If the OP asks an optimisation question, I take it on in good faith. How come you want to blame me?

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't consider that *lean* may mean *fast*. I think it more likely that he wanted something more *concise* that the `for` / `split` / `push` approach that he imagined. I guess we'll never know.